# why does my z-value change, if i use this geometry-nodes setup?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I am using this geometry nodes setup.

If i move my controller, the plane "reacts" like this.

I hoped/thought, it should have a constant z-height, which is just moved by the controller, instead the z value changes. Maybe i am too tired now to understand, but can somebody explain me why this happens!? and/or tell me, what i have to change so that the z value keeps constant, but just "moves" with the controller?

[image]

*** UPDATE:

This "should" be my node setup...thanks to Nicola:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the whole position of your controller (a vector: blue) to drive the Z (a scalar, grey) of your offset: see the noodle changing color here:

[image]

I can't remember now, but this is either taking the X position of the controller or the norm of the vector. This is why your Z seems to change depending on the X of the controller.

I don't have B3.0 right now, but I believe you should be able to just scale a vector field by 0 along X and Y. Or you can put a Separate XYZ and a Combine XYZ next to each other, connecting only the Z between the two, to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: thank you! i am stupid! of course i have to separate the z value first. OMG...Thanks!!!